# Strange EGL behaviour with X11 and nVidia driver

Tags: c++, opengl, x11, nvidia, egl

I have a strange problem at the moment, I have this sample application using GTK2, OpenGL and EGL. The strange behaviour I describe only happens on nVidia GPUs on Linux with the official nVidia driver. In the program you see a comment, if you dont use `glFlush` OR `glGetError` at this point in the code, the code will not draw the triangle, it will only display red (the clear color). If you call `glGetError` or `glFlush`, it works.

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

static EGLDisplay egl_display;
static EGLSurface egl_surface;
static EGLContext egl_context;

static void realize_cb (GtkWidget *widget)
{
    EGLConfig egl_config;
    EGLint n_config;
    EGLint attributes[] = { EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT, EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
                            EGL_NONE };
    EGLint surf_attrs[] = {
        EGL_RENDER_BUFFER, EGL_BACK_BUFFER,
        EGL_NONE
    };

    egl_display = eglGetDisplay ((EGLNativeDisplayType) gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay (gtk_widget_get_display (widget)));
    eglInitialize (egl_display, NULL, NULL);
    eglChooseConfig (egl_display, attributes, &egl_config, 1, &n_config);
    egl_surface = eglCreateWindowSurface (egl_display, egl_config, GDK_WINDOW_XID (gtk_widget_get_window (widget)), NULL);
    eglBindAPI (EGL_OPENGL_API);   
    egl_context = eglCreateContext (egl_display, egl_config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
    eglMakeCurrent(egl_display, egl_surface, egl_surface, egl_context);
    printf("GL Version: %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
}

static gboolean on_configure (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
    return FALSE;
}

static gboolean draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *expose, gpointer userdata)
{
    eglMakeCurrent (egl_display, egl_surface, egl_surface, egl_context);

    GtkAllocation alloc;
    gtk_widget_get_allocation(widget, &alloc);
    glViewport (0, 0, alloc.width, alloc.height);

    glClearColor (1, 0, 0, 1);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho (0, 100, 0, 100, 0, 1);

    glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f (1, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f (50, 10);
    glColor3f (0, 1, 0);
    glVertex2f (90, 90);
    glColor3f (0, 0, 1);
    glVertex2f (10, 90);
    glEnd ();

    /****************************
     * It does not matter if you call glGetError or glFlush here, if you do, it
     * works, if not, it only displays a red surface
     ****************************/
    //glGetError();
    //glFlush();
    eglSwapBuffers (egl_display, egl_surface);

    return TRUE;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *w;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    w = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (GTK_WIDGET (w), FALSE);
    g_signal_connect_after (G_OBJECT (w), "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize_cb), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (w), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK (draw_cb), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (w), "configure-event", G_CALLBACK (on_configure), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show (w);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -o gtkegl gtkegl.cc -lEGL -lGL $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0) -lX11
```

Comment: The [documentation for eglSwapBuffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglSwapBuffers.xhtml) says "eglSwapBuffers performs an implicit flush operation on the context (glFlush for an OpenGL ES or OpenGL context bound to surface before swapping." Looks like an Nvidia bug.

Comment: Well, even if Swap issues an implicit Flush, calling it explicitly does not do much harm: being issued when a command buffer has already been flushed, Flush just returns and does nothing. On a side note, luckily I\`ve got the proper hardware, so I\`ll give this code a try.

Comment: Confirmed. GL Version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.56, GTX 980Ti.

Comment: Glad it does not only happen to me :). Ive also posted this in the nvidia forums, but got no reaction at all yet.

Comment: @Nidhoegger …Got a question. Is GTK+ a requirement? Chances are the culprit is somewhere between GDK and EGL, for my Xlib-only EGL sample seems not to exhibit the issue.

Comment: GTK is a definitive requirement. i have written two xlib examples, one that works and one that does not.

Comment: I guess its some kind of race condition

Answer (score 0):

eglSwapBuffers is thread-context specific. If you somehow altered the rendering context from another thread then it fails.

I see couple possible errors:

1. You don't check eglMakeCurrent returning value. It may fail.
2. You don't synchronise draw_cb. It may be called from different threads simultaneously.
3. You call eglMakeCurrent from different places. They might conflict between each other.

Comment: It is ensured in my code (and also in the example above) that the drawing is only done in the same thread. Also before every draw the context is made current via `eglMakeCurrent`.

Comment: I see, but you don't check any return.

Comment: This is a minimal example which normaly does not contain error checking. I got a error checking version here and in my production code errors are checked